# Using a log scale on gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I am trying to change my scale on gnuplot. I had a file from which I am plotting the fifth and sixth columns, and I am trying to change the x axis to a log scale. I am using

> ```
> set logscale <x> <2>
> ```

but it is saing that 'x' is an invalid axis. Is there a way to find out what the "name" of my 'x' axis is so that I can use this command?

Comment: Could the down-voter please explain how I should improve my question?

Comment: This is not a programming question.

Comment: @BaummitAugen Gnuplot is a label that comes up here, and I think the answer lies in typing the right thing into the terminal/command window- I wouldn't know what else this would come under the umbrella term of other than 'programming'. If you know where my question would be better suited (or indeed have an answer!), please let me know.

Comment: This is a perfectly valid question for this forum. Could you please post the exact command you are using, and the exact error message the gnuplot gives you? `set logscale x` should be the right command. You might have to adjust the `xrange` so that it does not include negative values. Which version of gnuplot are you using?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From your question it's rather hard to see what you exactly want. Comment if this isn't what you're looking for. It sounds like you want to set the x axis to logscale base 2. It's done this way

```
set logscale x 2
```

In general, this is the command

```
set logscale <axes> <base>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I figured out my stupid mistake; I did not realise that the < > was meant to be omitted!